# Netbeans 8.2, build attempt fails to find msys2

Tags: c++, c, windows-10, netbeans-8, msys2

I am working on a building a netbeans project that requires msys. I have set the system environment variable PATH to point to the msys bin directory.

note : 
-The env. variable path is set correctly as in cmd line the result of command: PATH, displays the correct location "C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;"

however... all msys functions are evidently inaccessible because when I run commands: make --version, g++ --version, etc... they are not recognized.

When attempting to build the project in netbeans8.2 the build immediately fails to find the msys shell.

Comment: Did you set that environment variable after you started NetBeans? If so, close and reopen NetBeans. Are those specific packages installed in msys64?

Comment: -Yes I have tried restarting the Netbeans client, without success.
-Installed packages via msys shell commands: "pacman -S base-devel" and "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

Comment: Did you restart the command line program?

Comment: Did you tell NetBeans where mingw is and tell it use that compiler in your settings?

Comment: -Yes, I had restarted the cmd line after changing the path and the settings for the tool collection are as follows: Base Directory = C:\msys64\mingw64\bin, C Compiler = <Base Directory>\gcc.exe, C++ Compiler = <Base Directory>\g++.exe, Fortran Compiler = <Base Directory>\gfortran.exe, Assembler = <Base Directory>\as.exe, Make Command = C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe, Debugger Command = <Base Directory>\gdb.exe

Comment: [1] Your tool collection settings look OK, but just to be sure please update your question with a NetBeans screen shot of **Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools**. [2] What exactly is `<Base Directory>`? Is that just your shorthand for `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` within your comment, or is it something more than that? [3] I don't think it helps you, but for what it's worth I have these entries in my path on Windows 10: `C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;` and everything is working fine.

Comment: Please don't mix up MSys and MSYS2, these are two different projects.